# sails.js data from api loop through in view

Tags: json, sails.js, ejs

I am getting error while i am trying to loop through a json object. I am getting data from api and pass it to view.I tried to print the whole object their is no issue. If i try to loop trough , it is throwing error. But if i hardcode the response in controller( whatever response come from api ) it is working fine.

this is controller with hardcoded response

```js
module.exports = {
  index: function(req, res) {
    var request = require("request");
    request("http://app.coreosadmin.com/emp.json", function(error, response, body) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        var menuData=[{"id":"Dasboard","icon":"&#xE871;"},
                      {"id":"Subscriptions","icon":"&#xE871;"},
                      {"id":"Extensions","icon":"&#xE158;"},
                      {"id":"Adds Management","icon":"&#xE158;"},
                      {"id":"Client Management","icon":"&#xE158;"},
                      {"id":"User Management","icon":"&#xE158;"},
                      {"id":"Settings","icon":"&#xE158;"},
                      {"id":"Enums","icon":"&#xE158;"},
                      {"id":"Accounts","icon":"&#xE158;"},
                      {"id":"Reports","icon":"&#xE158;"}];
        return  res.view('homepage',{menus:menuData});
      }
    });
  }
};
```

This is my controller

```js
 
module.exports = {
  index: function  (req, res) {
    var request = require("request");
    request("http://someurl.com/emp.json", function(error, response, body) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        return res.view('homepage',{menus:body});  
      }
    });
  } 
};
```

this is my home view

```html
<div class="menu_section">
    <ul>
        <% menus.forEach(function(menu)  { %>
            <li title="<%- menu.id %>">
                <a href="index.html">
                    <span class="menu_title"><%- menu.id %></span>
                </a>
            </li>
        <% }); %>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its solved.  i had to use JSON.parse .

return  res.view('homepage',{menus:JSON.parse(body)});